# Could not find or load main class Mysql

Tags: java, mysql, compiler-errors, javac

I have problem with my java app compilation.

Folder structure:

src/LogServer.java (this is the main class)

src/SocketThread.java

I also use MySQL driver in it.
This files aren't in package.

When I'm running:

```
javac -classpath mysql-connector-java-3.1.14-bin.jar *.java
```

everything works fine.

See the compilation:

```
java -classpath mysql-connector-java-3.1.14-bin.jar LogServer
```

compiler says:

```
user@user-Inspiron-3543:~/workspace/LogServer/src$ javac -classpath mysql-connector-java-3.1.14-bin.jar *.java

user@user-Inspiron-3543:~/workspace/LogServer/src$ java -classpath mysql-connector-java-3.1.14-bin.jar LogServer
Error: Could not find or load main class LogServer

user@user-Inspiron-3543:~/workspace/LogServer/src$ java LogServer
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    at jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(java.base@9-internal/BuiltinClassLoader.java:366)
    at jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(java.base@9-internal/ClassLoaders.java:184)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.base@9-internal/ClassLoader.java:419)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(java.base@9-internal/Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(java.base@9-internal/Class.java:294)
    at LogServer.init(LogServer.java:22)
    at LogServer.main(LogServer.java:51)
user@user-Inspiron-3543:~/workspace/LogServer/src$
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use the -classpath argument.  In your classpath, you will need '.' to establish that your current directory is on the classpath and the mysql-connector-java-3.1.14-bin.jar.  So you put those two together in a list.  On Linux, the elements are separated by ':'.  On Windows, it is ';'.

```
java -classpath .:mysql-connector-java-3.1.14-bin.jar LogServer
```

Edit:massive editing

Comment: Actually I'm running java and javac from src folder where class and jar files exist. And it's not working

Comment: Then remove src from the commands java -classpath .;mysql-connector-java-3.1.14-bin.jar LogServer

Comment: I know, but it's not working. I'm running it on linux. That's weird, when I'm trying to compile other apps everything works.

Comment: Is there a method public static void main(String args[]) in LogServer?

Comment: added compiler answer

Comment: I revised my answer.

Comment: you wont believe how rare this information is. I went nuts trying to figure out why my simple jdbc program was throwing classNotFoundException